# Hasql: Error from variable substitution in 'SET' statement

Tags: postgresql, haskell, hasql

I'm trying to write a parameterized statement with Hasql to set a variable in PostgreSQL.

```
import qualified Hasql.Encoders as E
import qualified Hasql.Decoders as D

setOrganization :: Query Int64 ()
setOrganization = statement sql (E.value E.int8) D.unit False
  where
    sql = "set my_session.organization_id = $1"
```

The result from the above is:

```
ResultError (ServerError "42601" "syntax error at or near \"$1\"" Nothing Nothing)
```

Adding single quotes e.g.

```
    sql = "set my_session.organization_id = '$1'"
```

Gives this result when I run a query using the variable:

```
ResultError (ServerError "22P02" "invalid input syntax for integer: \"$1\"" Nothing Nothing)
```

Which does make sense since the `organization_id` is a `bigint` / `int8`.

Hard-coding the `$1` value in either format works. I've tried different Hasql types e.g. `E.text` and `E.unknown` and that does not work.

---

Update: Using the more primitive `execParams` function from `postgresql-libpq`.

```
execParams c "SET my_session.organization_id = '$1'" [Just (Oid 20, "1",Text)] Text
```

Unquoted variable gives `FatalError` result. Single-quoted variable gives `CommandOk`, but is wrong type  (not `bigint`) for later queries.

Comment: The error messages indicate that the `$1` place holder is not being substituted.

Comment: I think error reporting is without variable substitution. Using `$1` placeholder format works for `select ($1 + 4)`, so that format seems ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SET` command cannot be used with a prepared statement. This is a limitation of PostgreSQL. A *prepared statement* is a statement with optional parameters that can be executed several times with varying parameter values. All statements with parameters are prepared statements in PostgreSQL, regardless if you execute them only once or if you give them a name for reuse.

You'll have to construct a query string with a constant value and execute that.

Alternatively, you could write a function in PostgreSQL that runs the set command for you with dynamic SQL and call that function in a prepared `SELECT` statement with a parameter.

Comment: Since I'm including `False` the query is for a parameterized query instead of a prepared statement (This function in `libpq`, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQEXECPARAMS). Running the `SET` query with single quotes returns `commandOk`.

Comment: @Mikkel I guess what Laurenz means is that `SET` can't be used with a *parametric* statement. IOW, you need to hardcode the value into that statement. This limitation comes from Postgres, not Hasql.